# Spring security x-frame-option

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot web server which uses the httpWebSecurityAdapter.

I am trying to display some web pages (HTML CSS, javascript) in a div in my Angular app.
X-frame does not allow me to do it if enabled.
I would like to disable the x-frame options only for a certain type of request.

Right now I have it disabled for everything. I would like to do only for a certain URL.

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide multiple *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter* configurations. In other words, multiple security configurations for each of your url patterns.

Here's a sample configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    // @Order is to specify which WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should be considered first. This configuration has the highest priority.
    // This configuration is activated for url pattern: /home/**
    @Order(1)
    @Configuration    
    public static class DefaultSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
            http.antMatcher("/home/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()               
            .and().formLogin()
            .and().httpBasic();         
        }
    }

    // This configuration is considered after DefaultSecurityConfiguration since it has @Order(2).
    // This configuration is activated for url pattern: /registerUser/**
    @Order(2)
    @Configuration    
    public static class DisabledFrameOptionsSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
            http.antMatcher("/registerUser/**")             
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
            http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        }
    }
}
```